# Swift: from UIViewController to UITabBarController using swift code

Tags: swift2, viewcontroller, tabbar

I want to use swift code to make an action from UIViewController to UITabBarController, when user click the login button.

can help to make this problem, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to best practices, you should present a modal LoginViewController from your tabBarController or any root controller. This will cover the main screen with your login view.

Then when the user press login, you can call this to dismiss the login view and show the main screen.

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```